# Можно ли как-то выйти из цикла с помощью `break` в операторе `switch`?

Tags: java

Можно ли как-то выйти из цикла с помощью `break` в операторе `switch`?

Comment: [похоже да, если использовать метку](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: `switch` внутри цикла? или цикл внутри `switch`'а?

Answer (score 6):

Для передачи управления на следующую за циклом инструкцию надо этот цикл пометить меткой и указать эту метку в операторе `break`. Так можно передавать управление не только из оператора `switch`, но и из вложенного цикла.
Аналогичное правило действует для оператора `continue`: если использовать его с меткой, то можно передавать управление из вложенного цикла на начало внешнего.

Похожий вопрос есть на [английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823395/java-how-can-i-break-a-while-loop-under-a-switch-statement).

Вот фрагмент кода (чуть модифицированный) из приведенного там ответа:

```
loop:                             // Метка
  while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    typing = sc.nextInt();
    switch (typing) {
      case 0:
        System.out.println("You have choosen to finish!");
        break loop;               // Переход за конец помеченного цикла
      case 1:
        System.out.println("You have choosen 1");
        break;
      case 2:
        System.out.println("You have choosen 2");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("No such choice");
    }
  }
```

Но это практика не очень хорошая - она ухудшает читаемость и повышает вероятность ошибок. Лучше этого избегать. В большинстве случаев можно переосмыслить алгоритм и записать его иным, более ясным способом.

Comment: _Но это практика не очень хорошая - она ухудшает читаемость и повышает вероятность ошибок_ - спорное утверждение

Comment: @Grundy, да, но и то, что это утверждение спорное - это тоже спорное утверждение. Я утверждаю это исходя из собственного опыта и общения с коллегами. И лично для меня - это бесспорно. Я код без меток читаю намного легче.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, скорее дело привычки: иногда один goto смотрится намного читаемее чем куча условий/проверок

Comment: @Grundy в java нет goto. Вместо него сделали break с меткой.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, сути это в данном случае не меняет :)

Answer (score 6):

Иногда, когда кажется, что задачу не решить, или решить очень сложно, то нужно поменять методику решения задачи. И все сразу станет проще.

Выход по метке - это плохой способ, но почему то все его предлагают (потому что боятся предложить сменить методику решения задачи). Но есть сильно лучше способ. Сам цикл выносится в отдельный метод. Теперь метод может возвращать `true`/`false` и сам выход с `switch` сильно упрощается.

Но иногда можно пойти ещё дальше - данный код цикла выносится в отдельный класс (в java нормально на каждый чих создавать свой маленький класс). Теперь, класс может сделать расчеты и возвращать результат в полях.

Answer (score 1):

Можно на метку перейти. Как пример:

```
imoutofhere: while(sc.hasNextInt()){
    typing = sc.nextInt();
    switch(typing){
        case 0:
          break imoutofhere; 
        case 1:
          System.out.println("You choosed 1");
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("You choosed 2");
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("No such choice");
    }
}
```